# Ionic hiding and showing elements ng-show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, boolean

New to JS, Ionic framework, AngularJS. I'm trying to work with ng-show && ng-click to display the header on the event of a click on a button. I am still not getting the intended result, any ideas??

Here is my index:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as home">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar ng-show="display('on')" class="bar-balanced">
      <ion-content>
      <ion-nav-back-button class="bar-balanced">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

My controller:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.display = function (x) {

  if (x == 'on'){
    return true;
  }
  else if (x == 'off'){
    return false;
  }
}

})
```

My view:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="HomeCtrl as home">

  <ion-content class="splash">
  </ion-content>

  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <button ng-click="display('on')" class="button-large button-full button-clear">
      <a  class="button button-icon icon ion-log-in"href="#/login" >

      </a>
    </button>
  </ion-footer-bar>


</ion-view>
```

If i have missed anything will edit post with updates**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple issues here, first of all both the navbar and footer-bar elements should be inside the ng-controller element.  This will give the navbar access to the scope to determine if it should be shown or not.

Also, you should use a variable on the scope to determine if the navbar is shown, full example below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isNavVisible = false;
  $scope.displayNav = function(x) {
    if (x == 'on') {
      $scope.isNavVisible = true;
    } else if (x == 'off') {
      $scope.isNavVisible = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <ion-nav-bar ng-show="isNavVisible" class="bar-balanced">
    <span>Nav Content</span>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-nav-back-button class="bar-balanced">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
    <button ng-click="displayNav('on')" class="button-large button-full button-clear">
      <a class="button button-icon icon ion-log-in" href="#/login">Login</a>
    </button>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</div>

</html>
```

If you need to manipulate the nav from multiple controllers you could do that with a service like so

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('navService', function() {
  this.isNavVisible = false;
});

app.controller('RootCtrl', ['$scope', 'navService',
  function($scope, navService) {
    $scope.navService = navService;
  }
]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'navService',
  function($scope, navService) {
    $scope.displayNav = function(x) {
      if (x == 'on') {
        navService.isNavVisible = true;
      } else if (x == 'off') {
        navService.isNavVisible = false;
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="RootCtrl">
  <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
  <ion-nav-bar ng-show="navService.isNavVisible" class="bar-balanced">
    <span>Nav Content</span>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-nav-back-button class="bar-balanced">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
  <ion-view ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

    <ion-content class="splash">
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <button ng-click="displayNav('on')" class="button-large button-full button-clear">
        <a class="button button-icon icon ion-log-in" href="#/login">
Login
        </a>
      </button>
    </ion-footer-bar>


  </ion-view>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried this, it is still not working. I have added more code** 

"first of all both the navbar and footer-bar elements should be inside the ng-controller element. This will give the navbar access to the scope to determine if it should be shown or not."** 

Using MVC approach**

Comment: Make sure you're not declaring "ng-controller="HomeCtrl as home"" more than once, it should only be declared once at a level that emcompases both the nabvar and footer.

Comment: I have put it on the body tag which emcompasses the whole app. This controller has now been taken away from the view the issue still exist

Comment: If you're using an MVC approach then you'll probably need to manipulate the nav from multiple controllers since each view with likely use a different controller.  I just updated my answer with another solution that will allow you to do that using a service.  Services are singleton objects that can be injected into any controller.  Is that solution what you're looking for?

Comment: I have tried this and it reacts with the ionic framework in un-wanted ways printing out the nav bar on the login screen, then showing the back button on the next screen and allowing the user to go back to the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ng-click directive to change a value like this:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.displayItem = false;
    $scope.display = function (x) {

      if (x == 'on'){
        $scope.displayItem = true;
      }
      else if (x == 'off'){
        $scope.displayItem = false;
      }
    }

})
```

And then inside your View:

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-show="displayItem" class="bar-balanced">
  <ion-content>
  <ion-nav-back-button class="bar-balanced">
  </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Your View, will still the same

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-balanced" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as home">
<button ng-click="display('on')" class="button-large button-full button-clear">
  <a  class="button button-icon icon ion-log-in"href="#/login" >
  </a>
</button>
 </ion-footer-bar>
```

Make sure that both html refers to the same controller. Otherwise you will not have access to the $scope.displayItem property.

In case yo want to share data between different controllers, you should look for another alternative, like a Factory/service or property inside the $rootScope.

Comment: thank you, I have tried this with it is still not working I have added more code for clarification**

Comment: Could you add your app.js file.

Comment: You are using the same controller for a parent and a child view. 
Check this to get What I am trying to say.
https://plnkr.co/edit/YHIN0zyVg2DOBrFoxEZw?p=info

Comment: So are you saying:-  

1 - You can not share controllers 
2 - For each and every view you will need to generate a controller??

Comment: Yes, you can share controllers.
The thing is, you are declaring the controller in your index, and then inside an inner view you are declaring the same controller. 
I mean what you can not do is inject controllers into one another.

Comment: okay this makes sense, although when the view is pulled into index I'm unsure of why when an event triggers in that view this is not working